# Navigation menu overlap when scrolling down the page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

my site **[Deliver](http://constantin-entertainment.info/deliveryservice)** .I have set the current menu color and hover colors respectively.the issue is when we scroll down the header is getting fixed at the bottom with a slight height change.so the menu colors are overlapping which i feel not good . so i tried in css

```
.adjustsub nav ul li {
   height:40px !important;
   padding 0 0 0 0 ;
}
```

nothing seems to be working.Please help!!!

**EDIT
i need that in full height that of the header and when we scrolls down it should fit the fixed header size.reducing height doesn look good actualy**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this:

```
.adjustsub nav ul li {    
   height: 38px; /* decreased height */
}
```

Comment: i tried it with .adjustsub nav .menu li with ur css

Comment: no look the selector I have used in my answer is in your stylesheet there change..

Answer (score 0):

The height of `.menu li` was the problem. Use this CSS:

```css
nav .menu li {
    height: 38px;
}
```

---

#### Edit

```css
.fixed_slider header#header {
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 58px;
}
```